# How to wrap a Ruby/Rails method in a sub-class by altering the base class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop, polymorphism, object-oriented-analysis

I have a Ruby/Rails class `MyBase` defined as such:

```
module MyModule1
  class MyBase < Sinatra::Base
      register Sinatra::RespondTo
      register Sinatra::CrossOrigin

  ...
```

I define a sub-class of `MyBase` and has an API `someAction` that can be called:

```
module MyModule1
  module MyModule2

    class MySubClass < MyModule1::MyBase
      post 'someAction' do
        ...
      end

      ...
```

There are numerous other APIs in `MySubClass` not shown above for brevity.

I would like to time and then log the duration of each time any API is hit. I know how to time using the `STATSD` rails module and I know how to log too. But where/how should I put this timing code to keep my code DRY? I want to write it only once, preferably in the base class. But I don't know how to define a base class method that wraps the subclassed method and gets called anytime the subclassed method fires.

Answer (score 1):

Luckily this is a simple case of writing a different `post` method here that wraps the block you pass to it and calls the original `post`. It would be slightly more code if you were trying to wrap regular `def method`s.

Create a new `post` class method and call sinatra's `post` within it (this goes for `get`, `put`, etc):

```
module MyModule1
  class MyBase < Sinatra::Base
    register Sinatra::RespondTo
    register Sinatra::CrossOrigin

    def self.post_with_logging(action_name, &block)
      post action_name do
        start_your_benchmarks! # start your benchmarking

        block.call # this is your subclass' action block

        finalize_benchmarks! # finish up
        log_whatever!
      end 
    end
  end
end
```

Use this new `post_with_logging` method in your subclasses instead of the plain `post` method:

```
module MyModule1
  module MyModule2

    class MySubClass < MyModule1::MyBase
      post_with_logging 'someAction' do
        ...
      end
```

This is essentially wrapping the block and using the plain `post` method within. Hopefully this is pretty clear. Let me know if more explanation is necessary.

**Update:** in order to not have to change the subclass use `super`:

```
module MyModule1
  class MyBase < Sinatra::Base
    register Sinatra::RespondTo
    register Sinatra::CrossOrigin

    def self.post(action_name, &block)
      super action_name do
        start_your_benchmarks! # start your benchmarking

        block.call # this is your subclass' action block

        finalize_benchmarks! # finish up
        log_whatever!
      end 
    end
  end
end
```

And use your subclasses as normal.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without making any changes to the sub-class?

Comment: Override post itself and call super within

Comment: Diego, could you show me how to do that please? I don't know how to call the subclass's `post` method from within the parent class's `post` method.

Answer (score 1):

What are you looking for is a Rack middleware.

You can inject your own like this. Thanks to this the logic for the logging time of response is taken out completely from your Sinatra application as it works on the bottom level of request (Sinatra is built on top of raw Rack application).

```
class MeasureResponse
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    start = Time.now
    status, headers, response = @app.call(env)
    stop = Time.now

    log_time(start, stop)

    [status, headers, response]
  end

  private

  def log_time(start, stop)
    total_time = start - stop
    puts "Time of request: #{total_time}" #replace with your logger
  end
end


module MyModule1
    class MyBase < Sinatra::MyBase
        configure do
            use MeasureResponse
        end

       post 'someAction' do
         ...
       end
    end
end
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without making any changes to the sub-class?

Comment: There is no change to the subclass with this approach